# toFixed is not a function (javascript)

Tags: javascript, tofixed

If you look at my last javascript line | document.book.grandtotal.value= grandTotal. toFixed(2); |
after trying to run my code it gives me an error saying that "grandTotal.toFixed is not a function"
and if I try to remove toFixed it will work just fine. I don't know what's wrong it worked for everything except for this line

```js
function calc()

{quan_1= document.book.quan1.value;
quan_2= document.book.quan2.value;
quan_3= document.book.quan3.value;
quan_4= document.book.quan4.value;
quan_5= document.book.quan5.value;
quan_6= document.book.quan6.value;
quan_7= document.book.quan7.value;

unit_1= document.book.unit1.value;
unit_2= document.book.unit2.value;
unit_3= document.book.unit3.value;
unit_4= document.book.unit4.value;
unit_5= document.book.unit5.value;
unit_6= document.book.unit6.value;
unit_7= document.book.unit7.value;

total_1= document.book.total1.value;
total_2= document.book.total2.value;
total_3= document.book.total3.value;
total_4= document.book.total4.value;
total_5= document.book.total5.value;
total_6= document.book.total6.value;
total_7= document.book.total7.value;

totalPrice1= (unit_1 * quan_1)
 document.book.total1.value=totalPrice1 .toFixed(2);
 
totalPrice2= (unit_2 * quan_2)
 document.book.total2.value=totalPrice2 .toFixed(2);
 
totalPrice3= (unit_3 * quan_3)
 document.book.total3.value=totalPrice3 .toFixed(2);
 
totalPrice4= (unit_4 * quan_4)
 document.book.total4.value=totalPrice4 .toFixed(2);
 
totalPrice5= (unit_5 * quan_5)
 document.book.total5.value=totalPrice5 .toFixed(2); 
 
totalPrice6= (unit_6 * quan_6)
 document.book.total6.value=totalPrice6 .toFixed(2); 
 
totalPrice7= (unit_7 * quan_7)
 document.book.total7.value=totalPrice7 .toFixed(2); 

 
subTotal_= (totalPrice1 + totalPrice2 + totalPrice3 + totalPrice4 + totalPrice5 + totalPrice6 + totalPrice7);
document.book.subTotal.value= subTotal_ .toFixed(2);




taxValue= document.book.county.value;
calcTax= (subTotal_ * taxValue).toFixed(2)
document.book.tax.value= calcTax;

if (document.book.county.value == "0")
    
{alert("Please select a county");}



if (subTotal_ <= 15)
{shippingCost= "5.5"}
else {shippingCost= 5.5 + (0.0450 * subTotal_)}
document.book.shipping.value= shippingCost .toFixed(2);


grandTotal = (subTotal_ + shippingCost + calcTax );
document.book.grandtotal.value= grandTotal. toFixed(2);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">



<head>
 <title>  </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  
  <script src = "dynDate.js">
  </script>
  
  <script src = "beyond14.js">
  </script>
  
  <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "beyond14.css">
  
</head>

<body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 document.write("<h6>Last Modified on: "+document.lastModified+"</h6>");
</script>



<main>

<center>
<table>
<form name="book" id="book">
<tr>
 <th width="180px" > Cover </th> 
 <th width="270px"> Title </th>
 <th width="200px"> Product Type </th>
 <th width="200px"> Quantity </th>
 <th width="230px"> Unit Price </th>
 <th width="200px"> Total Price </th> 
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="align"> <img src="bk_book_woman.jpg" width="120px" height="150px" name="bookwoman" title="bookwoman"> </td>
 <td class="align"><input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="The Book Woman of Troublesome Creek" size="36"> </td>
  <td class="align"> <select size="1" name="type1" id="type1">
  <option> Audio </option>
  <option> Deck </option>
  <option> Fiction </option>
  <option> Music </option>
  <option> Non-Fiction </option>
  <option> Puzzle </option>
  <option> Reference </option>
  </select> </td>
 <td class="align"> <input type="number" size="3" name="quan1" id="quan1"> </td>
 <td class="align"> <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="15.50" name="unit1" id="unit1"> </td>
 <td class="align"> <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="total1" id="total1"> </td>

   
</tr> 
<tr>
 <td class="align"> <img src="au_dispatcher.jpg" width="120px" height="150px" name="" title=""> </td>
 <td class="align"><input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="The Dispatcher" size="36"> </td>
 <td class="align"> <select size="1" name="type2" id="type2">
  <option> Audio </option>
  <option> Deck </option>
  <option> Fiction </option>
  <option> Music </option>
  <option> Non-Fiction </option>
  <option> Puzzle </option>
  <option> Reference </option>
  </select> </td>
 <td class="align"> <input type="number" size="3" name="quan2" id="quan2"> </td>
 <td class="align"> <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="12.50" name="unit2" id="unit2"> </td>
 <td class="align"> <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="total2" id="total2"> </td>

</tr>

<tr> 
 <td class="align"> <img src="dk_gaia.jpg" width="120px" height="150px" name="" title=""> </td>
 <td class="align"><input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="Dreams of Gaia" size="36"> </td>
  <td class="align"> <select size="1" name="type3" id="type3">
  <option> Audio </option>
  <option> Deck </option>
  <option> Fiction </option>
  <option> Music </option>
  <option> Non-Fiction </option>
  <option> Puzzle </option>
  <option> Reference </option>
  </select> </td>
 <td class="align"> <input type="number" size="3" name="quan3" id="quan3"> </td>
 <td class="align"> <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="24.99" name="unit3" id="unit3"> </td>
 <td class="align"> <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="total3" id="total3"> </td>

</tr>

<tr> <td class="align"> <img src="bk_goldenInDeath.jpg" width="120px" height="150px" name="" title=""> </td> 
<td class="align"><input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="Golden in Death" size="36"> </td>
 <td class="align"> <select size="1" name="type4" id="type4">
  <option> Audio </option>
  <option> Deck </option>
  <option> Fiction </option>
  <option> Music </option>
  <option> Non-Fiction </option>
  <option> Puzzle </option>
  <option> Reference </option>
  </select> </td>
 <td class="align"> <input type="number" size="3" name="quan4" id="quan4"> </td>
 <td class="align"> <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="22.50" name="unit4" id="unit4"> </td>
 <td class="align"> <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="total4" id="total4"> </td>

</tr>

<tr> <td class="align"> <img src="bk_jefferson.jpg" width="120px" height="150px" name="" title=""> </td>
<td class="align"><input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="A Walk Down Historic Jefferson" size="36"> </td>
 <td class="align"> <select size="1" name="type5" id="type5">
  <option> Audio </option>
  <option> Deck </option>
  <option> Fiction </option>
  <option> Music </option>
  <option> Non-Fiction </option>
  <option> Puzzle </option>
  <option> Reference </option>
  </select> </td>
 <td class="align"> <input type="number" size="3" name="quan5" id="quan5"> </td>
 <td class="align"> <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="13.50" name="unit5" id="unit5"> </td>
 <td class="align"> <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="total5" id="total5"> </td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td class="align"> <img src="puz_millennium.jpg" width="120px" height="150px" name="" title=""> </td>
<td class="align"><input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="The New Millennium" size="36"> </td>
 <td class="align"> <select size="1" name="type6" id="type6">
  <option> Audio </option>
  <option> Deck </option>
  <option> Fiction </option>
  <option> Music </option>
  <option> Non-Fiction </option>
  <option> Puzzle </option>
  <option> Reference </option>
  </select> </td>
 <td class="align"> <input type="number" size="3" name="quan6" id="quan6"> </td>
 <td class="align"> <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="18.95" name="unit6" id="unit6"> </td>
 <td class="align"> <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="total6" id="total6"> </td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td class="align"> <img src="bk_signs.jpg" width="120px" height="150px" name="" title=""> </td> 
<td class="align"><input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="Signs & Symbols Sourcebook" size="36"> </td>
 <td class="align"> <select size="1" name="type7" id="type7">
  <option> Audio </option>
  <option> Deck </option>
  <option> Fiction </option>
  <option> Music </option>
  <option> Non-Fiction </option>
  <option> Puzzle </option>
  <option> Reference </option>
  </select> </td>
 <td class="align"> <input type="number" size="3" name="quan7" id="quan7"> </td>
 <td class="align"> <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="34.95" name="unit7" id="unit7"> </td>
 <td class="align"> <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="total7" id="total7"> </td>
  

</tr>

<tr> <td>TN County: <select size="1" name="county" id="county">
  <option value="0"> Select your county </option>
  <option value="0.0925"> Anderson </option>
  <option value="0.0875"> Cannon </option>
  <option value="0.0950"> Fayette </option>
  <option value="0.0800"> Johnson </option>
  <option value="0.0975">Williamson </option>
  </select> 

  <td colspan="3" class="alignR">  </td>
  <td class="alignR"> SubTotal: </td>
  <td class="align"> <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="subTotal" id="subTotal"> </td> </tr>
  
<tr> 
  <td colspan="4"> &nbsp; </td>
  <td class="alignR"> S&H: </td>
  <td class="align"> <input type="text" name="shipping" id="shipping" readonly="readonly" </td> </tr>
  
<tr> 
  <td colspan="4"> &nbsp; </td>
  <td class="alignR"> Tax: </td>
  <td class="align"> <input type="text" name="tax" id="tax" readonly="readonly"> </td> </tr>
<tr> 
  <td colspan="4"> &nbsp; </td>
  <td class="alignR"> Grand Total: </td>
  <td class="align"> <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="grandtotal" id="grandtotal"> </td> </tr>

<tr>
  <td colspan="6" class="align"> <input type="button" class="calc" value="Calculate Order" onclick="calc()"> </tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="6" class="align"> <input type="reset" class="del" value="Cancel Order"> </tr>  
</center>
</form>
</main> 
</html>
```

Comment: `"5.5".toFixed(2)` is what you're doing minimally, but `toFixed` is a number function, not a string function.

Comment: you need to remove all the spaces before `.toFixed()` Also, all those variables you set at the beginning are going to be strings, you'll want to convert them to use `toFixed()` on them..

Comment: @JDunken The space before the `.` is fine.

Comment: @ScottMarcus not where I work :)

Comment: Do JavaScript runtimes work differently where you work than what the ECMAScript standard says? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is to remove all spaces in there, between the call of the function and the variables, i hope its just a paste format issue.

Then you have to make sure that you are calling `toFixed` on a numeric type value, so you can convert to number first, to make sure you are not using it on a string.

so make it like:
`Number(someVariable).toFixed()`

Comment: It should be `Number(someVariable).toFixed()`

Answer (score 0):

> if (subTotal_ <= 15)
>   {shippingCost= **"5.5"**}

"5.5" is a string, not a number. You're trying to add it to two numbers, which changes everything into a string and then call **toFixed()** on that string (which works only with numbers). Change **"5.5"** into **5.5** !

Answer (score 0):

As the comments state `.toFixed()` is method of a `Number` type and you are attempting to use it on the `String` type. So, converting your data to a number will solve that issue. This can most easily be done by prepending a `+` to the string. Here's an example:

```js
var x = "5";
var y = "6";
console.log(x + y); // "56" because of string concatenation

console.log(+x + +y); // 11 because prepending a + converts string to number
```